# Passing an & through a javascript generated URL?

Tags: javascript, url, ampersand, html-escape-characters

I have this line of code that is executed when a ddl in my page is changed -

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Page", new { UserId = (string)null })/' + '@ViewBag.userId' + '?status=' + '@ViewBag.status' + '&amp;pageNo=@ViewBag.PageNo';
```

The link was working fine with just an &, but after checking the markup validator, http://validator.w3.org/check, it suggested I replace & with `&amp`; and I have done so in the above line of code. Now though, when I change the ddl `&amp;` literally appears in the url and the page does not work properly (as filtered by the ddl).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".ddl").change(function () { changePage(); });

 }); 

    function changePage() {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Page", new { UserId = (string)null })/' + '@ViewBag.userId' + '?status=' + '@ViewBag.status' + '&amp;pageNo=@ViewBag.PageNo';
}

</script>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the context for that line of JavaScript. I am assuming that it's within an inline script element or event. For URL's you must URL encode special characters, for HTML you must HTML encode special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are using XHTML by serving it as `text/html`

If the document was being parsed as XML then you would need to represent `&` as `&amp;` inside a script element, but since you are claiming the document is HTML, then you can't do that.

See [the compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) either

- keep your JS in an external file
- wrap it with CDATA markers
- use HTML instead of XHTML

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest I can think of is: you may want to put your javascript code in an external javascript and do the w3c validation again.